# Power BI SSO from single page react app which is already OIDC/OAuth

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, powerbi, single-page-application, openid-connect

We have an existing SPA React based application. We have our own custom built IDP which is OIDC/OAuth2.0 compliant and our web application implements the Authorization code grant flow to authenticate (OIDC) and authorise users within our company.

Now, we have to integrate Power BI into our SPA to allow users (user owns data) to launch either the Power BI website from within our UI application or even the other option is to embed the reports. We want to try both the options.

I have gone over the documentation to embed Power BI into a react app on the microsoft website but it looks like I have to register our company UI website with Azure AD and get an access_token to embed Power BI. Since our UI already uses OIDC/OAuth2.0 flow to login using our custom IDP how is Power BI SSO going to work on top of that?

The assumption in the above case is that the user is already signed into Azure AD so let us focus only on the SSO part of either launching app.powerbi.com from within our custom web application or embedding the reports.

Thanks
Jithu

Answer (score 0):

I am not an OAuth expert, but since your users aren't authenticated to your app with AAD I believe you can't use an [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to get a Power BI Access Token for the user.  You can always IFrame the [embedding url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure) of a report and let the browser handle auth, but that's not a seamless SSO flow.

So probably the best thing is to treat this as if it were App-Owns-Data embedding, and use your registered application's service principal to fetch its own Power BI Access Token, and use that to create a Power BI Embedding Token for the end user, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security#applying-user-and-role-to-an-embed-token).

Comment: Hi David, for brevity let me tell you that we use okta O365 integration for power BI and also our own spa app is added as a custom oidc/oauth with okta. Hence once we login to okta we are alao logged into Power BI. In this case how do you think we can approach this use case if SSO from our custom app to Power BI

Comment: Honestly I have no idea.  Perhaps you could ask Okta.